# SQL Agent on a standalone installation of SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, installation

I have three servers:

Server 1 - SQL 2012 - Primary server of high availability cluster

Server 2 - SQL 2012 - Secondary server of high availability cluster

Server 3 - Standalone SSRS

Server 3 is accessing Server 2 to generate reports.

Now I want to create report subscriptions on the SSRS server but the SQL agent service is not installed on server 3. I can't find any information on which features I need to install in order to install that service. I don't want to have a complete SQL 2012 installation on server 3 as it is acting mainly as a web server.

Does anyone know which features to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the database engine to install SQL Server Agent and Management Studio to manage it.